(When) is it an aveirah to NOT do a mitzvas asei?
I have heard conflicting opinions about not doing a mitzvas asei. Some seem to hold that one just misses out by not doing one, while others seem to class it as an aveirah to not do the mitzvah. Given that there are always mitvos asei that you could be doing, should we always be using any idle time to do so? It seems an impossible ideal for most people (and probably bad for the most people’s mental health).
As men, we put a lot of emphasis on time-bound mitzvos asei.  Not wearing tzitzis, not putting on tefillin, not hearing the shofar on Rosh Hashanah would all be considered a big deal, but would that actually be an aveirah?
Does this depend on how much effort would be required to do the mitzvah? e.g. hearing the shofar on Rosh Hashanah is a lot easier for me than shiluach hakan. Am I obligated to go out and find an appropriate mother bird that I can send away to take the eggs too so that I have done that mitzvah?  If so, how often must I do it?
EDIT: nb. for the purposes of this question, I'm defining aveiros as things that we receive punishment for (unless we do teshuva).

There are different types of mitzot asei. To quote the Sefer HaChinuch in his introduction:

וּמִן הַמִּצְוֹת אֵלּוּ יֵשׁ שֶׁאָדָם חַיָּב בָּהֶם לָקוּם לַעֲשׂוֹתָן בְּהַתְמָדָה, כְּגוֹן מִצְוַת אַהֲבַת הַשֵּׁם וְיִרְאָתוֹ וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהּ. וְיֵשׁ שֶׁחַיָּב לָקוּם וְלַעֲשׂוֹתָן בִּזְמַן יָדוּעַ וְלֹא קֹדֶם לָכֵן, כְּגוֹן מִצְוַת סֻכָּה וְלוּלָב וְשׁוֹפָר וּשְׁבִיתַת מוֹעֲדִים וּקְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וְכָל כַּיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶם, שֶׁיֵּשׁ לָהֶם זְמַן קָבוּעַ לַעֲשׂוֹתָן בַּשָּׁנָה אוֹ בַּיּוֹם. וְיֵשׁ מֵהֶן שֶׁאֵין אָדָם חַיָּב לַעֲשׂוֹתָן לְעוֹלָם אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן תִּהְיֶה סִבָּה שֶׁתָּבֹא לְיָדוֹ עִנְיָן שֶׁיִּצְטָרֵךְ לַעֲשׂוֹת בּוֹ אוֹתָהּ מִצְוָה הָרְאוּיָה לְאוֹתוֹ עִנְיָן, כְּאִלּוּ תֹּאמַר שֶׁנְּתִינַת שְׂכַר שָׂכִיר בִּזְמַנּוֹ מִצְוָה אַחַת, וּבְוַדַּאי אֵין אָדָם חַיָּב לִשְׂכֹּר פּוֹעֲלִים כְּדֵי לְקַיֵּם מִצְוָה זוֹ. וְכֵן קְצָת כַּיּוֹצֵא בָּהּ
And among the commandments, there are those that a person is obligated to do constantly, such as the commandment of loving God, and fearing Him, and that which is similar to it. And there are some that he is obligated to do at a specific time and not before then — such as the commandment of sukkah (dwelling in a hut), lulav, resting on the holidays, recitation of Shema and all that is similar to them — that have a set time to do them in the year or in the day. And there are some of them that a person is never obligated to do unless he is caused by a matter that comes to his hand that requires that commandment that is fitting for that matter. Such that you can say that giving the wage of a wageworker in its time is a commandment, while a man is certainly not obligated to hire workers in order to fulfill this commandment. And so [too,] some that are like this

So of the mitzvot asei you mention in your question, skipping tefillin or shofar would mean that you didn't do what you were supposed to do. Whereas, one is under no obligation to don a four-cornered garment (at least in theory) in order to put tzitzit on it, nor is one obliged to seek mother birds in order to send them away. Sefer HaChinuch in his discussion of each mitzvah tells you into which category a particular mitzvah falls.
If someone fails to perform a mitzvat asei that he is obligated to do (whether we're talking about something completely obligatory like shofar, or a person who puts on a a four-cornered garment and so is now obligated to attach tzitzit) it seems clear that such a person has committed "an aveirah" and would be liable to receive heavenly punishment.
For example, see Yoma 86a:

עָבַר עַל עֲשֵׂה וְשָׁב — אֵינוֹ זָז מִשָּׁם עַד שֶׁמּוֹחֲלִין לוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״שׁוּבוּ בָּנִים שׁוֹבָבִים״
If one violates a positive mitzva and repents, he is forgiven even before he moves from his place, i.e. immediately, as it is stated: “Return, you backsliding children"

which certainly sounds like he can expect some form of punishment if he does not repent (or at the very least has done something wrong which needs atonement).
Possibly even more instructive, in terms of the terminology you are using, is Rashi's comment there, in reference to mitzvat asei (my emphases):

למדת שיש עבירה שמכפרת בתשובה לבדה
Thus, there is an aveirah for which teshuvah alone atones.

Finally, in the context of your statement that "there are always mitvos asei that you could be doing", it's worth noting that the Sefer HaChinuch in his epistle lists precisely four mitzvot asei (along with two mitzvot lo taaseh) that are incumbent upon us at all times, namely:

to believe in God
to conceive of His oneness
to love Him
to fear Him


Just to expand on Joel K's excellent answer...
There are essentially 5 categories of Mitzvot Asei:

"Issur Asei" - a sin which has been phrased in the Torah as a positive action, yet reflects a prohibition (as understood by Chaza"l). For example, Leviticus 21:13 - a Kohen Gadol must marry a virgin is understood as a prohibition to marry a non-virgin.

(Eating outside the Sukka on Sukkot may be another example. Wearing a four-cornered garment without tzitit too, but this is similarly subject to dispute. see Tosafot Yevamot 90b, s.v. Kulhu)

A Once-per-lifetime Asei - For example, brit milah. There is a debate (Rambam/Ra'avad) if this Asei is transgressed retroactively at death, or if the transgressor lives in sin until he has circumcision, at which point the transgression is absolved.
A Time-or-situation-bound Asei - A Mitzvah with a set and limited time frame to fulfil. For example, listening to shofar or bringing a korban pesach.  Allowing this time frame or obligation to pass without fulfilling the mitzva is a sin, albeit one without action.
A voluntary Asei - A mitzva which carries no obligation to fulfil - sort of extra credit, if you like. (The delineation between this category and the previous category is sometimes unclear, and we have to rely on Chazal, Rishonim or other commentators to help define each mitzva.) For example, Shiluach Haken.
A "facilitative Asei" - An Asei which technically offers no reward, yet permits actions that would have been forbidden otherwise. For example, Shechita.


The Kotzeker Rebbe z'y's used to say: "Even the greatest tzadik, who has never sinned, must pray to the Aybershter that he NOT come to believe in himself, for his self-grandeur is worse than the worst aveyreh."
You see, a good yid lives between the open arms of Tohoreh and Kedisheh, which have various manifestations, e.g. haircut, tefillin, wine, mikveh and their absence respectively. And the general rule is: מעלין בקודש ואינם מורידים (one ought to rise in holiness and never retreat), e.g. if you go nozir, you gain in kedisheh, but if you interrupt it, you're called a sinner (although you might have been a tzadik before your neziress).
So, there's a certain hierarchy of Kedisheh, e.g. from chol to shabes and up to yom kipper. But internally, it depends on the state of your soul, which your body supports. Therefore, in ideal your physical acts must reflect your spiritual image, e.g. if once's mind is dirty, one is exempt from tefillin. If instead one's mind is pure and it's time for tefillin, then not wearing it damages one's image, which is not an aveireh in itself, but only in relation to the Aybershter, in Whose holy image a Ben Maylech was created.
As you say, one just cannot be holy 24/7 and that's the reason why there's Tohoreh. You kinda kosherise yourself over and over again in mikveh, toyreh, tfilleh in order to maintain your status as His holy vessel. So kedisheh is something objective (like possession), while tohoreh is something subjective (like lost-and-found aka teshiveh), which depends on you and your environment.
Der Kotzker Rebbe z'y'a also used to say: "If you haven't got a talless, wrap yourself in the four corners of the earth and pray." The truth of the matter is that as a yid deep inside you always know when, where and even why there is or isn't an aveyreh in your performing or not performing a mitzveh. The soul is what really matters, because it belongs to the Aybershter.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! You certainly bring an interesting angle from chassidus and one can also find such ideas in mussar seforim. Perhaps, this point is important to mention, but strictly speaking it may not be a part of the question asked as these violations might not be violations of halakha.

See pesachim 113b for 7 people who are in nudin by shemayim. They are people who are neglecting specific mitzvos aseh also see igeres hateshuvah in Tanya where it quotes koheles in regards to missing shema (though forgiveness is attained through teshuvah but) not being something that can be corrected as the light that could have been drawn down into the world by that shema can't happen now.
